# modulo with very large numbers and non-integer components

Tags: computational-mathematics

I'm trying to find the modulo of a very large number using Fortran.

The number is larger than the precision available.

Example:

[ 1e40 x log(2) ] modulo pi

I hoped there would be some clever theorem out there for a problem like this.

Comment: Do you have to use Fortran, or would you be satisfied with another tool? In any case a multiprecision library does this job, and Fortran probably has this, although I don't have first hand experience.

Comment: A good question. Fortran is the best tool for the job as the other part of the code needs parallelization. I have ways to solve this problem in a long winded non-elegant fashion already, but hoped for a nice solution. Fortran multi-precision, but it has it's limits around 1e36

Comment: [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/download.html) can do this very easily. The output of `default(realprecision,40); print(1e40*log(2)%Pi)` is `2.819539495`. If you use 50 digits precision, the answer is `2.819539497546425045`.  68 digits gives `2.81953949754642504239098617524548293127`.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this software - it's very useful!